# React native, problem with connecting to API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to connect to my API, when I want to login user, for example, I need to do any change in the file where is fetch or XMLHttpRequest, then I need to save and now login perfectly works... I had the same problem with `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`, btw when my laptop has different IP, I need to do this again... That's weird.

Here is my code:

`login.ts`

```js
export function login(email: string, password: string) {
    const data = {
      username: email,
      password: password,
    };
    console.log("Attempt to login: ", data);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", `${API}/login`);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", ContentType.APPLICATION_URLENCODED);
    xhr.send(encodeBody(data));

    xhr.onreadystatechange = async function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
        navigate('Home');
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(e.target);
    }
}
```

`Login.tsx`

```js
   <LoginButton title="Login" onPress={() => login(email, password)} />
```

I tried to change the method of calling to API and no changes happen, also tried to do a request in the same file as the components, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `login.ts`:

```
export function login(email: string, password: string) {
  const data = {
    username: email,
    password: password,
  };

  let formBody = [];
  for (let property in data) {
    let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(data[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");

  return fetch(`${API}/login`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body: formBody,
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      // processing result
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // processing error
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have it like that, encodeBody() function do it that, what you changed

Comment: Can you receive any response/error?

Comment: Nothing, any response or error, it is skipped for some reason

Comment: I tried with my api and i receive an error. can you give me your code of LoginButton component?

Comment: I find a solution, library for getting env variables didn`t work correctly, tkanks for help